# Regarding Filter HTML input option

Tags: 6, input-formats

I want to allow one more tag in Filter html Allowed HTML tags: <a> <em> <strong> <cite> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd>
<blockquote>.

I want to add <table> in this list. How can I edit this and in which hook I can modify this.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any hook for this. Go to Configuration > Text formats (path may vary slightly, but it is available in versions 6 to 8) and simply add tags to the list:

[image: Screenshot of page "linked" above]

Comment: @KrishnaMohan path and exact naming may vary a bit, but yes, it should work about the same from 6 to 8.

Comment: In addition to <table>, OP might want to add the other table-related HTML tags: <tr> <td> <th> <colgroup> <thead> <tbody> <tfoot>

Comment: @MarkG true enough, but I think that once he'll know where to edit this, he will figure what he really needs pretty soon :)